# What WAS the Dark Water?

Tags: the-pirates-of-dark-water

Recently I found a few episodes of "Pirates of Dark Water" on YouTube, and it got me waxing nostalgic for what was one of my favorite cartoons. I couldn't find all the episodes, but I've been reading up on the episodes and had a question.

What exactly WAS the Dark Water? In the cartoon, this black oily substance (similar in appearance to the alien symbiote from Spider-Man) was engulfing the world of Mer. At times it appeared to be intelligent, or at least alive, but I don't think it was ever stated where it came from or how exactly the thirteen treasures were supposed to stop it.

The show was cancelled before the story arc was completed, with Ren & crew only gathering half the treasures. Were there ever any statements by someone involved with the production as to what the overall antagonist (the Dark Water itself) actually was?

EDIT: For anyone not familiar with the show, [here's a link to the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pirates_of_Dark_Water) for it.

Comment: Word of God is that the final episodes were never written; http://piratesofdarkwater.net/information/show.html

Comment: Thanks, Richard - that's a real shame, this show had a lot of potential. It was up there with ExoSquad among my favorites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unofficial "[Pirates of Dark Water homepage"](http://piratesofdarkwater.net/dictionary/) has this to offer on the subject;

> From the entire series, seen first in episode 3, "Break-Up." The true
>   antagonist of the series. This "deathly liquid" is manufactured in the
>   center of Mer (by the Dark Dweller, I believe), but was held at bay
>   for eons by a magical seal produced by the Thirteen Treasures of Rule.
>
> After the Dark Dweller causes a rift in the ocean bed and in the
>   Treasures' seal, the Dark Water emerges in the seas of Mer, starting
>   the Year of the Black Tide. It engulfs anything in its way--ships,
>   debris, people, you name it. It also destroys nature--Andorus was
>   ravaged by the Dark Water, and Octopon was as well, though more so by
>   Morpho and his Dark Disciples--Bloth had actually plundered the city
>   and left it in ruin.
>
> The purpose of the entire series is to show Ren's quest to retrieve
>   all Thirteen Treasures of Rule and bring them home to Octopon so he
>   can place them in the lighthouse, which is the location of the new
>   Seal (or so it seems), to seal the Dark Water back into the planet's
>   core and to stop it from ravaging Mer.
>
> If the Dark Water wins, or if Ren and his friends lose (to the Dark
>   Water or to Bloth, or to some other malignant force we don't know
>   about)--the world is doomed to be literally engulfed by Dark Water,
>   and every bit of life in every corner of Mer will be destroyed by the
>   semi-sentient liquid.

It seems that on the occasions you can see a face in the Dark Water, you're actually seeing the face of the Dark Dweller.

Comment: I've been waiting to see if any alternative answers popped up, but I think this is probably the best explanation we'll find. Accepted!